# I've Got This Response From The GCM Server {"success":1} But the Notification not Come to the Device

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to Notify the Device by the Push Notification

I Received this Response From THE `GCM` Server

`{"multicast_id":8594338261894783737,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1355822022916886%8ae6056ef9fd7ecd"}]}`

But Still Not get the Notification

With Knowledge That --> `"success":1`

But I Think there is something Wrong Here --> `"canonical_ids":0`

---

This Is My Code ...

```
 private string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType = "application/json")
 {
     ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

     //
     //  MESSAGE CONTENT
     byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

     //
     //  CREATE REQUEST
     HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
     Request.Method = "POST";
     Request.KeepAlive = false;
     Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
     Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, string.Format("key={0}",apiKey));
     Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

     Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
     dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
     dataStream.Close();

     try
     {
         WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
         HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
         if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
         {
          Label1.Text = "Unauthorized - need new token";

         }
         else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
         {
             Label1.Text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
         }

         StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
         string responseLine = Reader.ReadToEnd();
         Reader.Close();

         return responseLine;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         return "error";
     }
    // return "error";
 }
```

and i call this method using

```
     string deviceId = "APA91bHomX3zb6Y87fb4GAjyj8zIaI-tt1n6ZFmgtmu16nmLW7ntwnOyv4BXMH7RzQWk3JrKdLjttJMxKzvpFd3Kmrid_RzsC3zR46GLJGiZKERXOSIR8fYReBEfz1f0G_FIm5bPttWUBDwz9jPuF2lS8RQh-0DKbw";
     string message = "some test message";
     string tickerText = "example test GCM";
     string contentTitle = "content title GCM";
     string postData =
     "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + deviceId + "\" ], " +
       "\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"" + tickerText + "\", " +
                  "\"contentTitle\":\"" + contentTitle + "\", " +
                  "\"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";

     Label1.Text = SendGCMNotification("AIzaSyBEvtrtbbfy2-p2zS8Zi8DweZiRy8M-nZc", postData);
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Response format in the GCM documentation: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#response

```
success     Number of messages that were processed without an error.
```

What I understand that to mean is that GCM was able to process that message, it does not mean that the message was successfully sent to the device. (E.g. The device might be offline and will receive it later, but the message was successfully processed).

"canonical_ids":0 Does not mean that there was an error, it means that there were no devices that needed their ID's updated. You can read more about canonical ID's here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#canonical

> On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well,
>   everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application
>   triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to
>   reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.
>
> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily
>   recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined
>   to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application.
>   This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the
>   device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration
>   ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the
>   canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the
>   response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your
>   server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will
>   stop working.

I would suggest adding some logging code to your client, to make sure that you are not receiving the message. Specifically in your GCMIntentService classes onMessage() method.

Comment: Exactly,that what I need ,  the problem was in `onMessage()` Method,
thank you .