# Success:1 still no notification in android

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification through GCM but I am getting:

```
{
  "multicast_id":4793018731783267982,
  "success":1,
  "failure":0,
  "canonical_ids":0,
  "results": [
    { "message_id":"0:1452928098906665%a69ccee8f9fd7ecd" }
  ]
}
```

but still no notification is coming. Here is my code:

```
//index.php code

 $app->get( '/notify',function () use($app)
         {
                   $response = array ();
                    $regId="device registration id";   //hard coded
                    $message="hi everyone.this is to notify you" ;
                    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
                    $message = array("price" => $message);
                    $db = new DbHandler ();
                    $result = $db->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
                    echoRespnse ( 200, $result);

            } );

//Dbhandler code 

public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {


    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=AIzaSyByR3xuTkhB-OZSNTlQqlwnqsLBzqXUWb0',  //server key 
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Note:I am running this API directly from advanced rest client instead of android device.I am getting success in response but no notification on device whose reg_id i have hard coded here.Please help

Edit=================
I have written this code on android end:

```
if (checkPlayServices()) 
{
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    if (regid.isEmpty())
    {
        new register().execute();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("hello", "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
    }
}

public class register extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
         String msg = "";
         try 
         {
              if (gcm == null) 
              {
                   gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
              }
              regid = gcm.register(AppConst.SENDER_ID);              
              Log.i("hello", "Current Device's Registration ID is: "+regid);     
         } 
         catch (IOException ex) 
         {
             msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
         }
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

In Mainfest I have added:

```
     <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

Comment: have u written code to receive notification in ur android app?

Comment: Having `"success":1` does not mean that the message has been sent successfully. It states in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) that the message has been processed without an error, it could mean the message is queued for sending. You could refer to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929790/ive-got-this-response-from-the-gcm-server-success1-but-the-notification-no), it could be helpful and might answer your question.

Comment: I am getting notification from server ip but not from domain www.example.com .Please tell me why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle a notification on an Android device:

```
  @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
   String message = data.getString("message");
   Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
   Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
   // Handle received message here.
 }
```

For more info visit : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/