# canonical_id zero in GCM - Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am struggling with a problem I am facing with GCM. The push notification is not send in my mobile phone:(. After sending a message from a simple form(I enter email of the user and the message),I get the following json response.

```
{
 "multicast_id":5448677994062381651,
 "success":1,
 "failure":0,
 "canonical_ids":0,
 "results":[{"message_id":"0:1463160271625523%cbfca9dcf9fd7ecd"}
]}
```

And this is my php file.

```
<?php
include("init.php");
$url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$message="";
$registration_ids = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info where email = '".$name."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($registration_ids,$row['token_id']);

    }
}

$message_send = array("Notice"=>$message);
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
    'data' => $message_send
);

$headers = array('Authorization: key='.$apikey,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
                );


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fields));


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === FALSE){
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
echo "done".$result;

?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Admin Area</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <label>Enter email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <label>Enter message:</label>
      <input type="message" name="message" rows="2" cols="30"/>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

What could be wrong? Could it be anything with the port numbers?

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream), `"success":1` is the number of messages that were processed without an error. It does not mean that the message has been sent successfully. It can also mean that the message is queued for sending.

Also, `"canonical_ids":0` does not mean that there was an error, it means that there were no devices that needed their ID's updated.

Check these related questions:

- [I've Got This Response From The GCM Server {"success":1} But the Notification not Come to the Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929790/ive-got-this-response-from-the-gcm-server-success1-but-the-notification-no)
- [Success:1 still no notification in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824859/success1-still-no-notification-in-android)
- [Android GCM server sent but GCM not pushing to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533655/android-gcm-server-sent-but-gcm-not-pushing-to-device)

Comment: thanks. I fixed it. I declared the wrong name of the service inside the android.xml file.haha..

Comment: Nice. :) Happy coding!